# Cannot edit postgis in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am currently trying to edit a layer in postgis by using qgis, but still out of luck. I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I guess it must be a very basic issue since I haven't found any question like this one.

The versions are:

- postgresql 9.3.5 + postgis 2.1.7
- qgis 2.12.2

These are the steps I have already followed. First I created a simple table with a geometry column

[image]

After that, I made a connection in qgis
[image]

Then, add it as a layer in canvas. At the end, when I start editing I see an error in the log window and I cannot figure out what is it about. There seems to be a problem in the cursor definition.

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: I have found out that I can add / edit features. However, I am still worried about the error messages shown in the info window. Would it be a problem if I go ahead with heavier edits? By the way, I am getting to know qgis and it is surprising to me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add what steps you took that enabled you to add/edit features as an answer to this question? I would say not to worry about those warning messages, but do be aware that there is no history of edits in PostGIS, so edit with care :)

Answer (score 1):

I just did ignore the messages and went ahead with editing. Everything ok so far. My edits are light though. I guess the problem could be related to the fact that the table was empty.

Thank you very much.